# How use Namespaces in sapui5?

Tags: sapui5

Someone can help with namespaces in sapui5, please. how to use it how to use it, I'm working with eclipse IDE.

I'm following a tutorial, and use this namespace, as would be the namespace with the structure of my project.

```
       controllerName="sap.ui.demo.db.controllers.App"
```

the structure of my proyect is:

databinding(proyectname)

->webcontent(folder)
  ->controllers(folder)
    app.controller.js

->databinding(folder)
  data.controller.js
  data.view.xml

index.html

I tried several ways and I have not been successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespaces are set in index.html while bootstrapping.
The property used to set is : data-sap-ui-resourceroots.
For example :

```
data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
            "sap.ui.demo.cart" : "./"
        }'
```

The above code sets the namespace and from now on 'sap.ui.demo.cart' will point to the folder where my index.html is present ( since I set the property to current folder (./) ). So for your case:

```
data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
                "sap.ui.demo.db" : "./"
            }'
```

Complete bootstrap :

```
<script
        id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
        src='resources/sap-ui-core.js'
        data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
        data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'
        data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
        data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
            "sap.ui.demo.db" : "./"
        }' >
    </script>
```

Comment: @RahulBhardwaj I am following an walkthrough tutorial about on UI5 and I am confused, so correct me if I am wrong. The resourceRoot will point the view/controller  to the root folder  or wherever developer want to point using sap.ui.demo.db. But what is "db" over here and in above explanation you have used cart as well. would you mind clearing my confusion.

Comment: You can choose any name for your namespace like "my.company.name".  Since, I want all my paths to start where my index.html is, I used "./". You can always provide the reference path inplace of "./". Eg: "my.meta.models": "./models_folder/myTestmodel_folder" . This means when I say -> "my.meta.models.someResoucename" , UI5 will search in path-> "./models_folder/myTestmodel_folder/someResourceName".